# The difference btw "Wire transfer" or "Bank transfer"

Tags: differences

As far as I understand, "wire transfer" is used for internal money transfer (within one bank) whereas "bank tranfer" indicates a money transfer from one bank to another (say, from American Bank to UniCredit). Am I right?  Is there a difference btw those two?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Where did you come by current understanding? What does a dictionary tell you about those two terms?

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

They actually refer to the same kind of money transactions which may take place within the branches of the same bank or from a bank to another bank.

***[Wire transfer, bank transfer or credit transfer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_transfer)***:

> - is a method of electronic funds transfer from one person or entity to another. A wire transfer can be made from one bank account to another bank account or through a transfer of cash at a cash office.

(Wikipedia)